# mongo query times out with $match on new $project field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to do a $match after a computed $project field and the following query times out:

```js
db.getCollection('bookings').aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "location_id": ObjectId("5c123423234234234")
    }
    },
    {"$lookup": {from: 'inspections', localField: "_id", foreignField: "bookingId", as: 'inspection'}},
    {
        "$project": 
            {
                "endDate": 1,
                "startDate": 1,
                "state": 1,
                "inspection": 1,
                "late": 
                    {
                        "$cond": [
                            {
                            "$and": [
                            {
                                "$lte": ["$endDate", new Date()]
                            },
                            {                                                        
                                "$eq": ["$inspection", []]
                            }, {
                                
                           "$in": ["$state", ["returned", "active"]]
                                },
                       
                            ]
                            }
                            
                            , true, false
                         ],
                    }
            }
    },
     {
          "$match": { "late": true }
     }
])
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?  The problem is the `"$match": { "late": true }"` part because when I try to `$match` on a field where we are looking at a non-computed field - it works fine.

Comment: Can you add your document to the question?

Comment: Try by setting the Cursor Time Out using the mongo shell command cursor.maxTimeMS()

Comment: why are you using $project there?  You can just do a regular $match  `{$match:{endDate:{$lt: new Date()}, inspection:[], state:{$in:["returned", "active"]}` - how do you know the timing out has to do with project and match?  Maybe it's $lookup -  do you have an index on "bookingId" in "inspections"?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone - it was a genuine time out and not an issue with the syntax of my query. I added an index and all was good.